# How to set up data plan for 3g modem for raspberry pi?

Tags: usb, wireless

I have seen several posts about how to connect a raspberry Pi to a 3g modem to begin transmitting data. [Here is an example of a modem I would like to use.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00381NBI6)

[image]

My main confusion is in how you get the the 3g modem set up in the first place. Do you have to register the modem with a 3G carrier? Also, is it possible to set up one data plan with many 3g modems using the same plan? I want to have many raspberry Pi's set up doing pretty minimal network activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how it exactly works in USA with 3G but usually you need to get a SIM card from a GSM provider that has data plan.

[image]

But - If you live somewhere in the US then you can avoid having multiple data plans for each SIM by using this amazing service called [Ting.COM](https://techsnap.ting.com) ([Sponsons the great SysAdmin show Techsnap](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/show/techsnap/))

**With Ting, you have 1 account, and pay for how much you use,** for 1 sim or 20 sims! Yea, all on one account and pay what you use from the same pool. I wish we had Ting in the Europe. I am sure if you call them UP you can get more info.

Comment: @ppumpkin follow up question, what kind of 3g usb stick is that?

Comment: Try and search for USB 3G with SIM - You should get local results. If you struggle for any reason comment here and I will try and help you some more.